# linux file system permission issue

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm deploying nutch.  At first I just left the index file under `/root/nutch1.0`.  This works fine when run from command line.  However, when I search from web, it always returns `0 hit`.

I finally found the reason:  It's because the index file is located under `/root` that causes the failure to open the file. Things returned to normal when I move the index file to another directory.

But my question is:

I didn't change the permissions of the index file (just `cp` xxx another-directory).  Why did the access rights change?

```
drwxr-x--- 12 root root    4096 Jun  1 14:49 root
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root    4096 Nov 16  2007 usr
```

I put files under `/usr` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a file, you need search ('x') permission on the directory the file is in, as well as read permission on the file itself.  Moving the file from a directory where the web server does not have search permissions to one where it does will cause the effect you see.

Comment: drwxr-x---

Does this mean:
for user itself,read,write,execute allowed
for user in the same group,read,execute allowed
for other users,none allowed?

Comment: @Shore Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: So,to read a file,should have "ALL" execute permissions of parent directories,besides the read permission of the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't access anything in the root directory unless you're root.

Look at the permissions on /root, it should be something like 700... the execute bit is set so than only root can "execute" the directory.  Execution permissions on a directory are what allow you to look at files inside the directory.

It's the same reason you can't "ls /root" while you're logged in as someone else.

Comment: the root permissions as follows:

drwxr-x--- 12 root root    4096 Jun  1 14:49 root

Comment: @Shore:  Is that from "ls -ld /root" ?

Comment: That means the directory has read/write/execute for user "root", read/execute for users in group "root", and nothing for anyone else. AKA 750.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're in group "root", and therefore can use the directory.  When using a web interface, you're likely in a program with its own user (in the Unix/Linux sense), which is probably not in group "root".  From the permissions you've listed, anybody can use the "/usr" directory.